# Is there any way to prevent users blocking conversation from a bot?

Tags: bots, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams, power-platform

I have a chatbot that sends msg to users. Some users think they don't need that information, so they block it.

I am searching for a solution that disables users from blocking conversations with bots.

Is it possible?

Thanks,
Gabor

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is any way to force a user to accept an incoming message. They have a right to block any contact they choose.  The only solution is to educate the user on why the flow bot should be allowed to send them a message.  But I don't know of any way to keep them from blocking it.